# why getNamespaceURI() always return null?

Tags: java, dom, namespaces

why getNamespaceURI() always return null? what's wrong in printNSInfo method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document input = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(args[0]);
    Element root = input.getDocumentElement();
    printNSInfo(root);
}

private static void printNSInfo(Node node) {
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        if (node.getNamespaceURI() != null) {
            System.out.println("Element Name:" + node.getNodeName());
            System.out.println("Local Name:" + node.getLocalName());
            System.out.println("Namespace Prefix:" + node.getPrefix());
            System.out.println("Namespace Uri:" + node.getNamespaceURI());
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }
        if (node.hasAttributes()) {
            NamedNodeMap map = node.getAttributes();
            int len = map.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                Node attr = map.item(i);
                if (attr.getNamespaceURI() != null) {
                    printNSInfo(attr);
                }
            }
        }
        Node child = node.getFirstChild();
        System.out.println(child);
        while (child != null) {
            printNSInfo(child);
            child = child.getNextSibling();
        }
    } else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
        System.out.println("Attribute Name:" + node.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("Local Name:" + node.getLocalName());
        System.out.println("Namespace Prefix:" + node.getPrefix());
        System.out.println("Namespace Uri:" + node.getNamespaceURI());
        System.out.println("---------------");
    }
}
```

the input xml file is:

```
<a:NormalExample xmlns:a="http://sonormal.org/" xmlns:b="http://stillnormal.org/">
    <a:AnElement b:anAttribute="text"> </a:AnElement>
</a:NormalExample>
```

when I debug in eclipse, `node.getNamespaceURI()` always return `null`, where am I wrong?

Comment: what type Node.ELEMENT_NODE does have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939468/retrieving-namespaces-from-element-in-java-using-dom), you need to set a flag `factory.setNamespaceAware(true)`, like this:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document input = builder.parse(args[0]);

    Element root = input.getDocumentElement();
    printNSInfo(root);
```

And the output is:

```
Element Name:a:NormalExample
Local Name:NormalExample
Namespace Prefix:a
Namespace Uri:http://sonormal.org/
---------------
...continue...
```

Comment: Oh that's it! thank you. but i have another question, what if the method printNSInfo() is like this: void printNSInfo(Document doc) {...}, the param is a Document, and I don't know namespaceaware is true or false

Comment: You need to build the document with `namespaceAware`, the `DocumentBuilder` has a method, `isNamespaceAware`, but the `Document` itself can not know if is namespace aware.

Comment: If the param document is build without namespaceAware be true, how to get its namespace info?

Comment: You can not, the builder dont keep the namespace!

Comment: public class NamespaceAnalyzer {
    public NamespaceAnalyzer() {
    }
    public Document check(Document srcfile) {
     Document naReport = null;
     // TODO: Implement    
        return naReport; 
    }
}
the check method:
Input: A well-formed XML document.
Output: A namespace report file using the namespace report format described by namespaceAnalysisReport.dtd that reports
How to analysis the input document namespaces info?