# Get Namespaces from an XML file

Tags: java, xml, namespaces

I have this XML file and I need to know the URI of the namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fe:Facturae 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:fe="http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2014/v3.2.1/Facturae" >
    <FileHeader>
    </FileHeader>
</fe:Facturae>
```

I am using Java (jdk16) and this piece of code in order to get them:

```
        try {
            
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File(FACTURA_MODELO_XML));
            Element element = doc1.getDocumentElement();
            
            logger.info("element         : {}", element.getNodeName());
            
            NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();
            
            if (attributes != null){
                for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++){
                    Attr attribute = (Attr)attributes.item(i);
                    logger.info("attribute.Name         : {}", attribute.getNodeName());
                    logger.info("attribute.NamespaceURI : {}", attribute.getNamespaceURI());
                    logger.info("attribute.Prefix       : {}", attribute.getPrefix());
          
                }
            }
         } catch (Exception ex){
            // print exception
         }
```

But running this code brings me the following result:

```
[main] INFO attribute.Name         : xmlns:ds
[main] INFO attribute.NamespaceURI : http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/
[main] INFO attribute.Prefix       : xmlns
[main] INFO attribute.Name         : xmlns:fe
[main] INFO attribute.NamespaceURI : http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/
[main] INFO attribute.Prefix       : xmlns
```

The name of the attribute is correct, but the NamespaceURI and the Prefix are not the values that I am looking for.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27715183?

Comment: Thank you @Parfait! Your post is what I needed. I needed to use .getLocalName() in order to obtain "fe" and "ds". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want the attribute's namespace, you want the attribute value.

Instead of

```
logger.info("attribute.NamespaceURI : {}", attribute.getNamespaceURI());
```

you should use

```
logger.info("attribute.Value : {}", attribute.getValue());
```

Then the output is:

```
element         : {}fe:Facturae
attribute.Name         : {}xmlns:ds
attribute.Value        : {}http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
attribute.Prefix       : {}xmlns
attribute.Name         : {}xmlns:fe
attribute.Value        : {}http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2014/v3.2.1/Facturae
attribute.Prefix       : {}xmlns
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. One more thing: I thought that getPrefix() would result in getting "ds" and "fe" in this two cases but instead only results in the first part. Is there any way of getting what is beyond the colon ":"?

Comment: Solved thanks to @Parfait: the method .getLocalName() is the one that is needed to obtain "ds" and "fe".